# What is the Schrödinger equation used for exactly?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

The [Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) is just another way of writing the conservation of energy, right? So how can you use it to find the quantum wavefunction? I mean in every example I've seen the wavefunction is calculated using sines and cosines so I don't see how you can use the Schrödinger equation to find a wavefunction. All I can see it being useful in is finding energy levels which doesn't help calculate the wavefunction. I'm pretty sure I'm wrong about everything I said because the Schrödinger equation is a big deal in QM, so can you please explain me what this is actually used for? I've had this question for ages now. Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Are you talking about the time-dependent or the time-independent Schrödinger equation?

Comment: well...both if you could...  first time independent then time dependent . thanx

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/581926/2451

Comment: One use of the wavefunction of a particle is to compute its expectation value of position, momentum, etc.  That is a big subject but you can find numerous examples of them on the web.

Comment: *The Schrödinger equation is just another way of writing the conservation of energy, right?* No, this is a mischaracterization of it.

Comment: BTW, you mentioned "sines and cosines"; these are encoded in the $|{\psi}\rangle$ that appears in various answers below, so they are still there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two equations commonly called the Schrödinger equation. Most physicists I know would prefer to call*:

$$i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}|\psi\rangle = \hat{H}|\psi\rangle$$

'the' Schrödinger equation. This is also called the 'time dependent' Schrödinger equation. It is the quantum mechanical replacement for Newton's second law:

$$ m \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\vec{r} = F(\vec{r}).$$

The TDSE tells you what $|\psi\rangle$ will be at time $t+dt$ if you know $|\psi\rangle$ at time $t$ and the operator $\hat{H}$. By incrementing by small time steps in this manner you can predict the state of a quantum system arbitrarily far into the future if you can solve the TDSE.

---

The *other* equation people call the Schrödinger equation is the 'time independent Schrodinger equation'. This is a *mathematical tool* used in the process of solving the full TDSE. This equation reads something like:

$$\hat{H}|E\rangle = E|E\rangle$$

where now we interpret the state $|E\rangle$ not an arbitrary state, but a state with a definite value of energy equal to $E$. The TISE then is read as an equation that, given the form of $\hat{H}$ tells lets you solve for the shape of states with each definite energy $E$. For many models it will turn out that this is only solvable for certain discrete values of $E$. That means that there are not states with intermediate definite energies, which in turn gives rise to the discreteness of atomic spectra etc (and the name 'quantum', ultimately).

---

*P.S. the notation $|\text{stuff}\rangle$ just means 'quantum state of system'. It's convenient because it means you can label a state $|E\rangle$ because it has energy $E$ and not get the symbol for $|E\rangle$ the state and $E$ the number confused.

Answer (score 9):

> The Schrödinger equation is just another way of writing the conservation of energy, right?

Wrong. The original motivation for Erwin Schrödinger can be read in his 1926 paper [An Undulatory Theory of the Mechanics of Atoms and Molecules](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.28.1049) (behind paywall, but freely readable copies can easily be found on the web).

Namely, the ansatz is the [Hamilton-Jacobi equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton-Jacobi_equation), whose solution $W(x,y,z,t)$ is seen as a set of constant-value surfaces in $(x,y,z)$ propagating in space as time $t$ changes, one (possibly disjoint) surface for a chosen constant value. Reinterpreting these surfaces as the constant-phase surfaces, or wavefronts, of some waves, gives us the idea of the quantum *wavefunction* (whose actual interpretation was not known until Max Born formulated [the rule named after him](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%27s_rule)).

Now, when we try to solve the time-dependent Schrödinger's equation, we find that it can be in general variable-separated for the time dimension $t$ to yield an expansion of the wavefunction in eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian operator. This then gives us the time-independent Schrödinger's equation for the individual eigenfunctions.

This is not much different from what we do when we solve e.g. the wave equation for oscillation of a drum-like membrane. The nodes of the eigenmodes of vibration of such a membrane form the famous [Chladni figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chladni_figures).

> I mean in every example I've seen the wavefunction is calculated using sines and cosines so I don't see how you can use the Schrödinger equation to find a wavefunction.

The cases when you can form a wavefunction with merely sines and cosines are very rare. They are the most trivial types of problems that you can solve with Schrödinger's equation. Even the [harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator) in quantum mechanical description requires the use of a set of functions that are definitely not sines nor cosines.

To understand how to use the Schrödinger's equation to find a wavefunction (I'm assuming you mean the eigenfunction of Hamiltonian, rather than time evolution of an arbitrary wavefunction), try reading the derivations of the solutions of various problems like [quantum harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator) and [hydrogen atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom#Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation).

Answer (score 2):

Essential knowledge about the Schrödinger-equation SE (I limit my post to the time-independent equation) is that it is an eigen-value equation.

I assume that you know the basics of linear algebra so if you take a, for instance a 2x2 matrix $A$, an eigen-value problem can be set up:
Let's assume

$$A= \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$$

there is the following eigenvalue problem:

$$ A v = \lambda v$$

that has a simple solution:   $\lambda_{1,2} = \pm 1$ and $v_1 =\left( \begin{array}{c} 1\\ 1 \end{array} \right)$ and $v_2 =\left( \begin{array}{c} -1\\ 1 \end{array} \right)$. In particular the space of solutions

$$ v= \langle v,v_1\rangle v_1 + \langle v,v_2\rangle v_2$$

spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$ is 2-dimensional.

The Schroedinger-equation  is basically the same with a couple of differences: the matrix $A$ is substituted by the Hamilton-operator $H$ and $\lambda$ are the energy (eigen)-values and $v$ corresponds to the wave-function $\psi$.

$$ H\psi = E\psi$$

However, the subtle difference of the SE to the linear algebra problem is that the space the eigen-vectors of this equation belong to is infinite (and called Hilbert-space). One strategy of finding the wave-function is searching for a basis in this infinite space. Evidently this is not so trivial. But the tools of mathematical physics provide us with a whole pool of special functions.

For instance let's look at the 1-dim. quantum harmonic oscillator. In this case we are lucky since eigen-vectors can be constructed from the Hermite-polynomials $H_n$ that have the following form (and are of infinite number):

$$\psi_n(x) = \left(\frac{m\omega}{\pi \hbar}\right)^{1/4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n n!}} \exp(-\frac{m\omega}{2 \hbar} x^2) H_n(x\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}})\quad \text{for} \quad n=0,1,2,3,\ldots $$

and the solution of the SE can be constructed as an infinite linear combination of these eigen-vectors:

$$\psi = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \langle \psi, \psi_n\rangle \psi_n $$

with $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is the scalar product on the Hilbert space.
We are even more lucky: Here (that's not always the case!) each element of the infinite basis even fulfills the eigen-value equation:

$$H\psi_n =E_n \psi_n \quad \text{with} \quad E_n =\hbar\omega (n+\frac{1}{2})$$

Of course, there might be problems which do not require to compute the eigen-vectors,
where the computation of the eigenvalues is sufficient. This also happens in linear algebra. But the eigenvectors, i.e. for the SE the wave-function, fulfills an essential role in the SE-eigenvalue problem.

A final word: the domain where the problem is posed also plays an essential role. In case of the harmonic oscillator it is $(-\infty,\infty)$, but for infinitely deep potential well it is $[-a, a]$. In the latter case the basis of the Hilbert space (here you might indeed get $\sin$'s and $\cos$'s) is a completely different one to the basis of the Hilbert space in case of the 1-dim. harmonic oscillator.

Moreover, symmetry and dimension plays a crucial role:
Again, an appropiate basis of the Hilbert space for the 3-dim. hydrogen atom is completely different to the one's already mentioned.